# How to colored datepicker fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I created a booking form and I'm using [Pikaday datepicker plugin](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) on my page.And my booking form is for hotels that is why I have empty days,rezerved days and available days and I want to show these days colored on datepicker and I created picture to show what I want to do actually.. how can I do this with jquery using arraylist ? any idea ?

[image]

image was example

and here is my codes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.flexdatalist').flexdatalist({
    minLength: 0,
    searchContain: true,
  }).on('select:flexdatalist', function() {
    $('#checkin').trigger("click");
  });

  assignPicker = function(id, whenClosed) {
    if (typeof whenClosed !== 'function') {
      whenClosed = null;
    }

    return new Pikaday({
      numberOfMonths: 2,
      field: document.getElementById(id),
      format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
      minDate: new Date(),
      firstDay: 1,
      maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
      onSelect: whenClosed
    });
  }

  var checkoutPicker = assignPicker('checkout', function() {
    $('#select').trigger("click");
  });

  var checkinPicker = assignPicker('checkin', function() {
    var maxDate = this.getMoment().add(15, 'days');
    checkoutPicker.setMaxDate(maxDate.toDate());
    checkoutPicker.setMinDate(this.getDate());
    checkoutPicker.setDate(null);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

input,
select {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/css/pikaday.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/example/flexdatalist/flexdatalist.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="" class='flexdatalist' data-min-length='1' list='languages' name='language' />
        <datalist id="languages">
          <option value="PHP">PHP</option>
          <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
          <option value="Cobol">Cobol</option>
          <option value="C#">C#</option>
          <option value="C++">C++</option>
          <option value="Java">Java</option>
          <option value="Pascal">Pascal</option>
          <option value="FORTRAN">FORTRAN</option>
          <option value="Lisp">Lisp</option>
          <option value="Swift">Swift</option>
          <option value="ActionScript">ActionScript</option>
        </datalist>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" class="checkin" id="checkin" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" class="checkout" id="checkout" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <form action="" method="get">
          <select name="select" id="select">
            <option value="0">Choose</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
          </select>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.anitur.com.tr/example/flexdatalist/flexdatalist.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[click to see on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/jBNMPx)

edit: with array list or anything way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to you CSS

```
.pika-single.is-bound{

  background:blue;
}
.pika-table{
    background:green;
}
.pika-table th{
  background:orange;
}
.pika-button{
    background: purple !important; 

}
```

Comment: no there is no any problem with css I know how can I do that with css the question is how can I do this with jquery using arraylist ? if field has `.rezerved_days` than apply this css or if field has `empty_days` than apply this class bla bla